# Macro to Loop Through Rows Until Empty Value, Copy Values, and Save Those Results to CSV?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that will loop through rows in the active Excel worksheet.  Each loop iteration will copy the values of column A, B, and C.  If the first cell is blank, I want to end the loop UNLESS the empty cell is in row two.  Then I want to continue with the loop.  Ultimately, after all the data is copied, I want to write that copied data to a CSV file.  Is this possible?

[image: Excel Worksheet]

I tried recording a macro, but the solution isn't at all robust, as it doesn't use loops, rather hard-coded `Range Selects`:

```
Sub Export_to_CSV()
'
' Export_to_CSV Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:C1,A3:C27").Select
    Range("A3").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    ChDir "C:\CSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CSV\MacroCSV.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you requirements are **exactly** as you have written them, this should work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export_To_CSV()

Dim wkbMain as Workbook, wkbCopy as Workbook
Dim wksMain as Worksheet, wksCopy as WOrksheet

Set wkbMain = ThisWorkbook
Set wkbCopy = Workbooks.Add

Set wksMain = wkbMain.Sheets("mySheet")
Set wksCopy = wkbCopy.Sheets(1)

With wksMain
  .Range(.Range("A3"),.Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy wksCopy.Range("A1")
End With

With wkbCopy

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim x as Integer
    For x = 2 to .Worksheets.Count
        .Sheets(x).Delete
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\CSV\MacroCSV.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solution is much more robust.  I am running into one major issue.  The only data captured in the CSV file is "Key Milestone #6" in cell A1.  Any idea what could be going wrong?